# Unclear token error in logs

Tags: sharepoint-server

While viewing logs I can see many records like this:
SPApplicationAuthenticationModule: Incoming token does not contain an actor

It's SharePoint 2016 On-premise and correlation id leads to connection with Office online server.

Any idea why it's 'Unexpected' level and where to look?

Answer (score 1):

What's the actual problem when you are using office online server ?

For the error : SPApplicationAuthenticationModule: Incoming token does not contain an actor .

Firstly, I suggest to check if you are using system account or not , please using a normal user account to access and monitor the ULS log .

Secondly, make sure the certificates were installed on OOS server and SP server if you are using Https.

- You have to add the SharePoint servers self-signed certificate in  WAC
  server Trusted Certificate store(Local Computer).
- You have to add the WAC server certificate in the all SharePoint
  server Trusted Certificate store(Local Computer).

Comment: I'm not using system account. It's usual user. Certificates are ok as well.